# Envio via FormCollection de valores monetários

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-3

Estou precisando enviar para um método no Controller, os valores preenchidos na coluna Pagamento_Valor conforme Figura abaixo:

[image: Figura 2]

Ao clicar no botão verde, envio via post, os valores da lista abaixo que gerou a tabela:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.vmListPagamentos)
{
     <tr class="odd gradeX">
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Matricula)</td>
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)</td>
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empresa_DtEntrada)</td>
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empresa_DtSaida)</td>
           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Pagamento_Valor)</td>
           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.DtPagamento)</td>
     </tr>
}
```

O problema está na concatenação dos valores monetários. O FormCollection, ao passar as informações para o controller, separa os valores do atributo "item.PagamentoValor" com virgulas. E o valor do campo também possuí virgula. 
Para ficar mais claro observar a imagem abaixo:

[image: Método]

Eu não imagino como pegar esses dois valores da string sem usar o Split(','). Mas se eu usar o split para quebrar essa string em duas, ele irá quebrar em 4. Por trabalhar com valor monetário, não quero ficar fazendo gambiarra para ficar concatenando esses valores. Existe outra forma de fazer esse envio de valores para uma action no controller sem ser via FormCollection?
Por que também tentei enviar o Model como parâmetro e não foi..

Answer (score 4):

Para isso, você irá precisar adicionar o pacote [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) no **Nuget**.

> Install-Package BeginCollectionItem

Após isso altere sua `view` para:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PagamentoConfirmed3", "Controller"}))
{

    @foreach (var item in Model.vmListPagamentos)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Pagamento", item)
    }
}
```

Fazendo isso, você precisa criar a [PartialView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview(v=vs.118).aspx) **_Pagamento.cshtml**

Sua **PartialView** ficará assim:

```
@model Models.Pagamento// Seu Model vmListPagamentos aqui

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("vmListPagamentos"))
{
   <tr class="odd gradeX">
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Matricula)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Nome)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Empresa_DtEntrada)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Empresa_DtSaida)</td>
       <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Pagamento_Valor)</td>
       <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.DtPagamento)</td>
 </tr>
}
```

E em seu `controller` você envia seu **Model**, ficando assim:

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult PagamentoConfirmed3(Model model){...}//Passe seu Model aqui
```

Feito isso, os valores digitados estarão todos dentro de `model.vmListPagamentos`. Basta fazer um `foreach` e utilizar como bem entender.

[Nesta pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999%20begincollectionitem) você encontra diversas respostas, aqui no SOpt, sobre a utilização.

Comment: Valeu pelo retorno Randrade. Tentei usar o esquema que vc me passou, mas estou me deparando com um erro. O "=> item" está com erro na PartialView, exibindo a seguinte mensagem: "The name 'item' does not exist in the current context"
Ele foi referenciado na página conforme vc orientou.

                   @foreach (var item in Model.vmListPagamentos)
                                    {
                                        @Html.Partial("_Pagamento", item)
                                    }

Comment: @GleisonFrança Desculpe, falha minha. Altere o `item` por `Model`. Alterei a resposta para você ter uma ideia.

Comment: Valew pelo retorno Randrade, consegui exibir a tela com a lista preenchida sem erros seguindo seu esquema. Ao clicar no botão o evento é disparado e acesso a action. Porém, o parametro Model está nulo. O que fiz de errado?
Eu tenho uma list dentro de uma viewModel que segue esse padrão:

public List<VW_PAGAMENTOS> vmListPagamentos { get; set; }